# Unable to enumerate USB device - RHEL 7.9

Tags: rhel, boot, hardware, error-handling

I get this error when booting up:

usb usb5-port2: unable to enumerate USB device

Its a Gigabyte server, any advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: Run `dmesg -w` in a terminal, and while it is running, unplug & re-plug your USB devices one by one and watch the output. If you find that plugging in a particular device causes the message to re-appear, test that USB device in another USB port, and in another computer if possible. Test the port that was associated with the error by plugging in a USB device that you know works well. From the results, you should be able to figure out whether the fault is associated with the device or with the port.